# How to remove DNS options from systemd-resolve

Tags: systemd, dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I'm unsure how to change the list of DNS options that resolvconf finds when connecting. `systemd-resolve --status` outputs

```
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: serverine
       DNS Servers: serverone
                    serveronev6
                    servertwo
                    servertwov6

Link 2 (wlp0s20f3)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.4.4
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

and `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` outputs:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver serverone
nameserver serveronev6
nameserver servertwo
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver servertwov6
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search .
```

with server one and two being two dns servers i want to use, and v6 being the ipv6 addresses. i want to get rid of the google dns options under link2 and only use mine in global; how would I accomplish that with systemd-resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the appropiate nameservers using the DNS= setting on /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

That resolv.conf is entirely managed by resolved and you should not edit it.